# Lazy Loading not working on setting scrollable: {virtual: true} in Kendo Grid

Tags: jquery, css, scrollbar, kendo-grid, virtualization

I am a beginner working on Kendo Grid. I wanted to load the data on demand in the grid, like :

- I set the page size to 50, when a user scrolls down to 50 rows, the grid should retrieve next 50 rows from database and display it on demand.
- To do this, I changed `"scrollable: true"` to `"scrollable: {virtual: true}"`. But this disables scrolling in the grid.

I am stuck, let me know if anyone has faced the same issue and found any solution for it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set few true serverpaging as true in your datasource as well. I will post a demo of Datasource portion, hope that helps someone.

```
  var sharedDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            autoSync: true,
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/Home/GetJson",
                    dataType: "json"
                }

            },
            schema: {
                type: "json",
                data: "data",
                total: "total",
                model: {
                    id: "Id",
                    fields: {
                        Id: { editable: false },
                        HostName: { editable: false },
                        Scope: { editable: true },
                    }
                }
            },
            serverPaging: true,
            serverSorting: true,
            pageSize: 50
        });
```